# Sort ArrayController multiple columns and directions

Tags: sorting, ember.js

Is it possible to sort the content of an ArrayController by both multiple fields and multiple directions? Would this work, trying a sort like "**lastName ASC, zip DESC**":

```
App.TableController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['lastName', 'zip'],
  sortAscending: [true, false]
})
```

I searched posts here and through the Ember docs but couldn't find any information on multiple 'sortAscending' options.

Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible, as noted by [this discussion.](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/extend-ember-sortablemixin-to-allow-sorting-multiple-properties-in-varying-orders/3753) You'd have to write your own sorting function to do it.

Comment: Thanks! That's a helpful link. Especially to know that Ember is moving towards using `Ember.computed.sort` more.